# How can I remove picture metadata like in Windows 7?

Tags: metadata

Windows 7 has a nifty feature where user can remove a picture's metadata

In windows 7 user goes to Properties > Details tab > "Remove Properties and Personal Information"

Does Ubuntu have similar feature? How can I remove a picture's metadata using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some options.

With **exif**:

```
sudo apt-get install exif
cd to/folder/
exif --remove *
```

With **exiftran**:

```
sudo apt-get install exiftran
cd to/folder/
exiftran -d *
```

With **jhead**:

```
sudo apt-get install jhead
cd to/folder/
jhead -purejpg *
```

With **exiv2** (for multiple formats support):

```
sudo apt-get install exiv2
cd to/folder/
exiv2 rm *
```

Comment: exif only works on jpeg? what about other formats, like png?

Comment: exif should work on pngs too.

Comment: exif looks great. but are the other two options necessary for removal or are they just other manipulation tools to explore? can i just use exif and see all metadata and remove all metadata, or do I need all 3?

Comment: The best seems to be exiv2. Execute `exiv -h` in a terminal for help about your last comment!

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get install exiv2` I see this warning: `WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  exiv2
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? n`

Comment: I ended up installing libimage-exiftool-perl (8.60-2) from the Ubuntu Software Center. It's more than I need but it didn't have the `packages cannot be authenticated` warning.

Comment: Sorry for making yet another comment but today I didn't get the warning when I tried to install `exiv2`.

Comment: Probably you successfully disabled them!

Answer (score 0):

Phatch contains the ability to remove metadata tags for a batch of photos as well as other nifty batch photo edits.
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/phatch/

Comment: do you know if ubuntu has a "built in" ability to remove the metadata? or is an app required to accomplish it?

Comment: As far as I know there is no built in way to do out of the box. They have the difficult task of deciding what goes on the 700MB CD so things like image manipulation have to be installed by the users who need them to conserve space.